# Define abstract django models field

Tags: django, django-models

I need to create an abstract Django model and I want to enforce all models-inheritors redefine that field.
I've tried that but got an exception:

```
from django.db import models


class AbstractField(models.Field):
    description = "Abstract Field"

    def __init__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("You have to redefine your field in model.")


class MyAbstractModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    redefine_me_please = AbstractField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class MyNotAbstractModel(MyAbstractModel):
    redefine_me_please = models.CharField(verbose_name='Name', max_length=255)
```

An exception was `NotImplementedError` on `makemigrations` action.
Any idea how to imitate abstract field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot work that way - model fields are instanciated when you define the class, so with this implementation you will never be able to just import your models file.

The proper solution is to use a custom metaclass - which has to inherit from django's own models metaclass. Here's an example implementation (you'll certainly have to refine it somehow) in Python2 syntax, I let you check the doc for the small syntaxic differences for Python3.

```
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

class MyAbstractField(object):
    pass

class MyAbstractModelType(ModelBase):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs):
        must_check = True
        djmeta = attrs.get("Meta", None)
        if djmeta and getattr(djmeta, "abstract", False):
            must_check = False
        if must_check:          
            for attrname, value in attrs.items():
                if isinstance(value, MyAbstractField):
                    raise TypeError("Class %s must redefine %s" % (name, attrname))

        return ModelBase.__new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs)

class MyAbstractBase(models.Model):
    __metaclass__ = MyAbstractModelType

    foo = MyAbstractField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class CorrectConcreteModel(MyAbstractBase):
    foo = models.IntegerField()

class IncorrectConcreteModel(MyAbstractBase):
    pass
```

With this code, a concrete MyAbstractBase subclass (for Django's definition of "concrete model subclass") that does not redefine `foo` will raise a TypeError at import time, making the problem immediatly obvious to the coder. A possible improvement could be to check that `foo` is a proper model field (ATM anything else than a MyAbstractField will be accepted).

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you implement inheritance with OneToOne relationship.

What you want to do may be: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Comment: Can you please add to your answer the link to docs or code of that realization?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance